# Disabled fast boot CSM, now can't get into UEFI-BIOS

Tags: linux, windows, bios, uefi

After reading this [lengthy article](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI) on UEFI and the recommendation to disable CSM for dual boot setups I went ahead and did so. Now I can't boot into UEFI-BIOS (normally pressing either <kbd>Delete</kbd> or <kbd>F2</kbd> on boot).

A bit more info>
Part of the problem may be my misunderstanding of what constitutes a 'dual boot' system.

Right now I have Linux and Windows, but they are each on totally separate SSD's and I only switch between them via the BIOS on boot. So technically I believe I have a single boot setup and shouldn't have messed with CSM.

To make matters worse, I attempted a BIOS firmware reset thru the Windows rescue menu, holding down shift on restart.
Not sure what I did but didn't manage any BIOS reset or update and when rebooted get no video signal, just a black screen.

How do I get back into UEFI BIOS?

Comment: You disabled fast boot? or CSM? because these are 2 totally different concepts!

Comment: Just don't worry ok? In my opinion, you haven't lost any files, you reset your firmware settings to default, and now EFI boot is disabled (I believe you have a CSM BIOS rather than a Modern EFI BIOS) Same happend to me, You just need to get into your BIOS and enable EFI boot again, and there are ways to do that.

Comment: thanks, in my journey into Linux installs now feel I've broken everything that CAN be broken. Yes I know fast boot & CSM r 2 different things.Still need to figure out how to reset, or reinstall my UEFI firmware. Have done it before, but think that required first booting into UEFI! Bit of a chicken and egg problem. At least have resolved the black screen, my MOBO thinks I have 2 monitors when I have one...more digging. Maybe a way to reset UEFI thru command line? Or a switch on my AsusX99II-A MOBO?

Comment: wmic bios get /format:list  give s brief summary of BIOS settings but nothing detailed and nothing CSM related

Comment: also tried this method to enter BIOShttp://www.dell.com/support/article/ca/en/cabsdt1/SLN143038

Comment: So, now you can get into windows again?

Comment: yes, posted answer below

Comment: Can you still get into BIOS settings by holding "Shift" while restarting? If yes, go to your BIOS settings and reset it's settings to default state. **Note: there's no guarantee that it allows you to enter BIOS settings by pressing "F2" or "Del" button again, but I can assure you it doesn't delete your Windows/Files, !!!Even If You're Not Able To Boot!!! It doesn't mean that your files are gone, it's your bootloader. So, do it at your own risk, ok?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP
I checked MOBO manual for ASUS X99A2- solution was to short 2 pins for 10-15 seconds after first shutting down and removing power cord. If someone knows of a software only solution...